# Move Windows 7 BCD to another disk

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, multi-boot, bcd

I have installed a Windows 7 on a SSD disk on a system containing two disks: The SSD and HDD. I have found however after installation that despite my boot disk is the SSD (that is, where my Windows 7 is installed) my boot table is on the HDD. That means that my SSD is marked as boot and my HDD is marked as system. I would like to move the boot MBR from the SATA to the SSD. I don't need to clone any disk, just move the system partition tables to my SSD, so my multiboot starts from my SSD instead the slower SATA.

To the editor: A boot MBR is NOT a BCD (the loader). I reroll back to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use free [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD) to move boot record (it's called BCD - Boot Configuration Data) to SSD drive. Start EasyBCD and look into "BCD Backup/Repair -> Change boot drive".

Of course you should backup the boot record to a file first and it's a good idea to create a USB with bootable Windows 7 installer in case boot loader gets damaged.

Generally EasyBCD is a great tool to manage all kind of Windows boot options, easier to use than Windows' buit in BCDEDIT - Boot Configuration Data Store Editor.

Comment: That's what I did. In fact, I used the bcdedit in the console to move to my SSD the boot area, and then BCDEdit to add the linux partition, that was lost in the process. Now under W7 I can see that my SSD is qualified as boot AND system, while keeping my multiboot (terms arguably interchangeable for their real meaning for Windows systems)